# Why is angular provider not defined?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to integrate [hello.js](http://adodson.com/hello.js/) into [rdash-angular](https://github.com/rdash/rdash-angular) using [ng-hello](https://github.com/gonzalo123/ngHello) see also the ng-hello [blog post](http://gonzalo123.com/2015/03/02/building-a-angularjs-provider-for-hello-js-library/).

The error that I get when the page loads is:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: helloProvider is not defined(anonymous
>   function) @ dashboard.min.js:2

I've included Hello and ng-hello in bower.json and installed successfully,
which copies to

- src/components/hello
- src/components/ng-hello

The app structure defined by rdash-angular minifies the vendor scripts and references them in file lib/js/main.min.js, then the app source files are minified and referenced in file js/dashboard.min.js

**index.html**

```
  <!-- SCRIPTS -->
  <!-- build:js lib/js/main.min.js -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="components/hello/dist/hello.all.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="components/ng-hello/dist/ng-hello.min.js"></script>
  <!-- endbuild -->
  <!-- Custom Scripts -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dashboard.min.js"></script>
```

**ng-hello.js**

```
(function (hello) {
    angular.module('ngHello', [])
        .provider('hello', function () {
            this.$get = function () {
                return hello;
            };

            this.init = function (services, options) {
                hello.init(services, options);
            };
        });
})(hello);
```

**module.js**

```
angular.module('RDash', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.router', 'ngCookies', 'ngHello']);
```

**routes.js**

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Route configuration for the RDash module.
 */
 angular.module('RDash').config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', helloProvider,
     function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, helloProvider) {

         helloProvider.init({
               google: '0123456789MYAPPTOKEN.apps.googleusercontent.com'
         });

         // For unmatched routes
         $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

         // Application routes
         $stateProvider
             .state('index', {
                 url: '/',
                 templateUrl: 'templates/dashboard.html'
             })
             .state('tables', {
                 url: '/tables',
                 templateUrl: 'templates/tables.html'
             });
     }
 ]);
```

As mentioned earlier, the error that I get is helloProvider is not defined.
Why is this happening?

Comment: The first `helloProvider` in your config list, should be passed as a string, don't know if it is a typo error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When injecting scopes, i believe you should wrap it like this 'helloProvider'.

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Route configuration for the RDash module.
 */
 angular.module('RDash').config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider', 'helloProvider',
 function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, helloProvider) {

     helloProvider.init({
           google: '0123456789MYAPPTOKEN.apps.googleusercontent.com'
     });

     // For unmatched routes
     $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

     // Application routes
     $stateProvider
         .state('index', {
             url: '/',
             templateUrl: 'templates/dashboard.html'
         })
         .state('tables', {
             url: '/tables',
             templateUrl: 'templates/tables.html'
         });
 }
]);
```

Also while defining the provider, its good to define with verbose name like 'helloProvider'.

Answer (score 1):

your module definition takes a string representation of the module in the array, followed by a function that accepts these strings as input parameters.

in the following line, you should be providing a string, not a variable, i.e.:

```
angular.module('RDash').config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', helloProvider,
```

should be

```
angular.module('RDash').config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'helloProvider',
```